# How to create an interpolated string from a string?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a system that gets templates from a database, then fills in values programmatically:

```
//using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

var template = "Hello {0}"; // this string comes from the database
var name = "Joe";
var message = FormattableStringFactory.Create(template, new object[] { name });
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

This code sample works, but I can only use the numeric notation. I'd like to store the templates in the database in the interpolated string format, like this:

```
var template = "Hello {name}";
```

This throws a `Run-time exception (line __): Input string was not in a correct format.`

Is it possible to create an interpolated string from a string?

Comment: String interpolation is just syntax sugar. I am not sure about your needs, but did you think about this scenario ? 

1.) know what tokens/ placeholders you have in template;
2.) Pass `template`, `found tokens`, data packed in `Dictionary<Token, TokenValue>` into factory
3.) Iterate over found tokens and replace placeholders template.Replace(tokenItem, tokensData[tokenItem].Value)

Comment: Both approaches share the same problem for human edits: if it's multiple indexes, then human can screw up with numbers; if it's `name`, then human may screw up with letter and type it as `nmae`. I'd keep using old good `{0}` and will simply split long ones into several simpler, e.g. instead of "Good day {0}, would you like to do {1}" I'd make two sentences. And, well, you can still screw up even with `{0}`.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in a (probably) weird way.... but it works so i try to share with you my conclusion:

```
public static string ExtendedStringFormat(this string source, List<Tuple<string, string>> values)
    {
        string returnvalue = source;
        foreach(Tuple<string, string> my_touple in values)
        {
            returnvalue = returnvalue.Replace(string.Concat('{', my_touple.Item1, '}'), my_touple.Item2);
        }
        return returnvalue;
    }
```

And you can call it like below:

```
            List<Tuple<string, string>> lst =  new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
            lst.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test","YAYYYYYY"));
            lst.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test2","YAYYYYYY22222222"));
            string ret = "hem... hi? {test}, {test2}";
            ret = ret.ExtendedStringFormat(lst);
```

Comment: The current implementation uses string.Replace, which is what we're trying to avoid.

Comment: Ok, sorry that my answer not helping you :(
Btw what you not like of string.Replace()? Is mutch fast and memory efficient that many alternatives.